# SQL - Deleting duplicate rows without leaving original

Tags: sql, ssms

How to delete duplicate rows based on select columns without leaving original? In this example, deleting based on Name and Animal.

```
ID   Name   Animal   Fruit
1    Bob    Dog      Orange   
2    Adam   Dog      Orange
3    Bob    Dog      Apple
4    Adam   Cat      Orange  
5    Bob    Cat      Apple
6    Bob    Hamster  Apple
7    Adam   Cat      Apple
```

So the expected result would be:

```
ID   Name   Animal   Fruit  
2    Adam   Dog      Orange 
5    Bob    Cat      Apple
6    Bob    Hamster  Apple
```

Comment: I see no duplicates in your data.  Please explain your logic.  Also define what you mean by "original".

Comment: Please post some sample data also the question is vague. How would you explain the original record?

Comment: @GordonLinoff Based on matching values in select columns (e.g. Bob and Dog in rows 1 and 3). In this case, we would delete both 1 and 3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a delete with join the subquery grouped by name and animal  having count > 1

```
     delete m 
     from my_table m 
     inner join (

        select name, animal
        from my_table
        group by name, animal
        having count(*) > 1 

     ) t on t.name = m.name
        and t.animal  = m.animal
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:
first, select the duplicates in a subquery.
then, delete all results

```
delete from mytable T 
left join 
(select count(*) cnt, Name, Animal 
from mytable 
group by Name, Animal) X 
on t.Name = X.Name 
and t.Animal = X.Animal
where cnt>1
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do this using `exists`:

```
delete from t
    where exists (select 1
                  from t t2
                  where t2.name = t.name and t2.animal = t.animal and t2.id <> t.id
                 );
```